# SQL Join causes multiple additions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure this question has been asked before so please help steer me in the right direction if so, but my question is this.

I have a SQL Query that gathers sales data from 2 tables - `CustomerInvoice`, and `CustomerInvoiceDetail`

`CustomerInvoice` contains generic data about the invoice, such as customer name, address etc, but it also includes freight amounts.

Example table data (one record per Invoice Code):

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ Invoice Code ║ Customer Name ║ Address                    ║ Freight ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════╣
║ INV-200000   ║ ABC Co        ║ 1 Apple Street, FRUITVILLE ║ 20      ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

---

`CustomerInvoiceDetail` contains info on each line item from the invoice. Often there are multiple line items on the one invoice.

Example table data (multiple records per Invoice Code)

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ Invoice Code ║ Part Number ║ Quantity ║ Price ║ ExtPrice ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ INV-20000    ║ 50505       ║ 2        ║ 5     ║ 10       ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ INV-20000    ║ 51325       ║ 3        ║ 2     ║ 6        ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

---

This means my `JOIN` results in multiple results from the `CustomerInvoice` table, meaning in the sample case, freight will be $40 : 2 line items x $20 freight.

My query as follows, multiplies the freight amount (on table `CustomerInvoice`) by the number of line items (on table `CustomerInvoiceDetail`)

What I'm currently getting, is sales price + (freight * number of line items on `CustomerInvoiceDetail`)

What i need, is sales price + one instance of freight (in sample case, 10 + 6 + 20)

```
SELECT 
  SUM(cid.ExtPrice + ci.Freight ) AS 'Sales'
FROM CustomerInvoice ci
JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail cid ON ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
```

If anyone had any suggestions or a resource they can point me to to research this, I would be most grateful! Thanks again.

Comment: What is your desired output? Perhaps it's just me, but I'm not exactly seeing a *question* here... can you clarify?

Comment: and the question?

Comment: @Santi - not just you...

Comment: Sorry guys I got so wrapped up in explaining my situation that i forgot to describe my desired output!!!! Have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate *before* you do the sum:

```
SELECT (cid.ExtPrice + ci.Freight ) AS Sales
FROM (SELECT SUM(ci.Freight) as Freight
      FROM CustomerInvoice ci
     ) ci CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(cid.ExtPrice) as ExtPrice
      FROM CustomerInvoiceDetail cid
     ) cid;
```

Because of the `JOIN` you are multiplying the number of rows for `Freight` for each invoice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon! I'm only used to simple SQL language, would you mind explaining your answer a little more? Or perhaps point me to some documentation?

Comment: don't you need to group by and join on an id column?

Comment: @Hogan . . . The original question appears to be looking for just the total overall.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can avoid subqueries by doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
  cid.InvoiceCode, SUM(cid.ExtPrice) + MAX(ci.Freight) AS 'Sales'
FROM CustomerInvoice ci
JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail cid ON ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
GROUP BY cid.InvoiceCode
```

**Sample Output:**

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Invoice Code ║ Sales       ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ INV-20000    ║ 36          ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ INV-20001    ║ 100         ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ INV-20002    ║ 50          ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

You can add a `WHERE InvoiceCode='INV-20000'` to select only one invoice if need be.

Comment: You need a group by

Comment: @Santi Is there any way to now group these invoice codes to give me a total sales value, including freight? Using `MAX` only selects one freight amount - the largest one

Comment: Using `MAX` in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` selects max *per group*, which in this case, is an invoice. When testing this in SQL Server I used varying freight amounts, and it returned the correct amount for each. Unless you mean a grand total of all invoices, in which case this would be a *subquery* in your `FROM`, and your select would be `SUM(Sales)`